# Elastic Search 5.6.4 pom transport issue

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

We are pointing to Elasticsearch 5.6.4. I used below entry in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I created the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:5.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.4.4:compile (version 
managed from 5.6.4)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.2:compile
```

Can someone help to resolve this. I need elasticsearch-5.6.4.jar, but I am getting run time issues.

Comment: Please add the rest of the pom

Comment: @circket_007 : Can not past the complete pom.xml. how to share it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
this resolved my issue

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</pre>
```